# How an ordering system should work. Web api

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

Based on the examples from the Internet I made this database, but I have some problems using it
[image: Schema]

How should I add ExtraItem to the order?
For example if I put in my orders a food item then I send a POST request to the server which returns a new created entry. What should I do next in order to add an Extra to that order? I have `FoodItemExtraId` but I don't know the `OrderFoodItemId` to make a POST request to `OrderFoodItemExtra` table.
Or maybe this schema is not correct?

Comment: Yeah, the whole extra item thing might be going down the wrong path, you should likely just add to the existing order

Comment: I'd say "being an 'extra'" is a property of a Food Item, not justfying a separate model / entity type in itself... if you look at the cols: they are literally the same (except for naming).

Comment: @Fildor but food item can have many extras and i want the client to be able to add some or nothing

Comment: But do you add extras to the order or to a food item on the order? And whatever the answer: should you?

Comment: I do not know where I should add extras, but i defenetly need that ability to choose extras. I will try to add them directly to order as TheGeneral suggested.

Comment: Why do you have an artificial identifier for all your entities? For example, the primary key of `OrderFoodItem` could be comprised of `FoodItemId` and `OrderId`.

Comment: The problem with this question from the start is we had no idea what a food item extra was. Secondly this is just a design decision everything we can suggest you can rationalize for or against. It really depends what this industry is, whether its restaurant or a bakery or a shopping store. You are the only person who understands your domain, you are the only person who should be making this decision on relationships

Comment: As such, i am not sure its a good fit for stackoverflow

Comment: @JanezKuhar just for convenience. FoodItemId and OrderId is alternate key

Comment: @TheGeneral knowing that its a restaurant and that food item extra it is an addition to the food item, can i use your first answer as a solution?